# creating campaign from python mailchimp api

Tags: python, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am using mailchimp3 python api

```
from mailchimp3 import MailChimp

client = MailChimp(mc_api='', mc_user='')

client.campaigns.create(data={})
```

I want to create a campaign but unable to understand what the 'data' should be in this case. Also, I want to put HTML in the email so any help in implementing this would be great. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Campaigns data is dict type.

[format reference: line 36](https://github.com/charlesthk/python-mailchimp/blob/master/mailchimp3/entities/campaigns.py):

```
data = {
    "recipients": object*
    {
        "list_id": string*
    },
    "settings": object*
    {
        "subject_line": string*,
        "from_name": string*,
        "reply_to": string*
    },
    "variate_settings": object* (Required if type is "variate")
    {
        "winner_criteria": string* (Must be one of "opens", "clicks", "total_revenue", or "manual")
    },
    "rss_opts": object* (Required if type is "rss")
    {
        "feed_url": string*,
        "frequency": string* (Must be one of "daily", "weekly", or "monthly")
    },
    "type": string* (Must be one of "regular", "plaintext", "rss", "variate", or "absplit")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**data** is the json payload you send to mailchimp's api

Please refer the docs for more details on what kind of data needs to be sent to the api

refer :- https://mailchimp.com/developer/reference/

ex :-

{
    "email_address": "r.siva@alientt.com",
    "status": "pending"
}